# how to connect to remote mssql using php

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, freetds

I can connect fine to the remote mssql using tsql from terminal but i cannot connect to the server from php. 
I installed freeTds, unixODBC and set the configuration in freetds.conf

Connection code tried

```
  $myServer = "x.xx.xxx.xxx";
$myUser = "testuser";
$myPass = "testpwd";
$myDB = "Testdb"; 

 //connection to the database
  mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass);
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
```

I get a 500 Internal errror , can anybody guide me how to connect to the remote mssql server from php.

Comment: have you recompiled PHP and/or loaded the MSSQL module? http://php.net/manual/en/mssql.installation.php

Comment: Could you include the 500 error message you're getting from your logs? Then we may be able to narrow down the problem. Rob's suggestion is a good first thing to check.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
(ip instead of localhost if remote).

**PHP**

```
   <?php

    $myServer = "localhost";
    $myUser = "testuser";
    $myPass = "testpwd";
    $myDB = "Testdb";

    @mysql_connect("$myServer ","$myUser","$myPass") or die ("could not connect to MySQL");
    @mysql_select_db("$myDB") or die ("No database");

    echo "sucess";

    ?>
```

Comment: pretty sure mysql functions won't work against a SQL Server :)